# Porting an Excel Optimization Model to R

Tags: r, optimization

Apologies straightaway if this question is not appropriate for this forum...I've already been downvoted out of the house on Stack Overflow...

I have built an optimization model at work in Excel....but Excel solver is not the best, to put it kindly. I get a different answer every time I run it...

I'd like to try implementing it in R, both to teach myself a bit and to see if I can get something that is more useful. I'm not a complete R beginner, but I'm not far off.

Here's the setup:

There are a number of projects that the organization may pursue. Each project has

- a dollar cost for the complete project
- an "importance" weight - these are normalized so that the entire set
  sums to 1
- a funding level - these are the decision variables, how much funding
  do I give it
- a "value curve" that translates funding [0%,100%] to value [0,1]

The value curves can be of three types

1. linear %funding=value i.e. 50% funding = 0.5, 75% funding = 0.75,
   etc
2. exponential - there is a parameter (rho) that describes the shape of
   the curve
3. S-curve

So for a given project, you set a funding level, consult it's value curve to determine where on the interval[0,1] it falls, and multiply that by the weight. This gives you what I call the "realized value".

The model picks funding levels that maximize the sum of the realized values subject to the constraint that you don't go over the dollars available.

Any hints on how to start pursuing this in R?

Comment: This is indeed off topic here. It probably could be on topic on [SO] with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). In addition, question that amount to "any hints on how to start..." are too broad.

Comment: The fact that you keep getting different solutions, highlights a problem with your optimization problem. Know that migration to R will not solve this problem

Comment: I'll delete the question as it wasn't my intent to run afoul of the community rules...I followed a link from https://r-dir.com/community/forums.html to get here...but with regards to the problem, I disagree.  The issue is that the base excel solver keeps converging to local extremes.  My organization has one license for Frontline's Premium Solver for Excel, and given the same spreadsheet it consistently finds roughly the same solution (+/- 0.005%) every time.  But since we only have one license it's on a shared machine that I can't necessarily always access....hence my desire to move to R.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have some functionality working in Excel, use [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) to make a working outline of a brand new R package (`devtools::create`) and to create a unit testing infrastructure (`devtools::use_testthat`).

Learn how to write unit tests with the `testthat` and translate the major working functionality of your Excel program into unit tests. You'll have tests like

```
test_that("Excel component X computes Y", {
  expect_equal(my_r_fn_that_doesnt_exist_yet(1.2, 3, 5), 6.25)
})
```

After you've got the tests that describe the major functionality, go write the code for these functions one at a time until you pass your tests.